# Mobile Safari IOS will scroll bottom page automatically when reloading page

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, reactjs, mobile-safari

I'm using react and as soon as I reloading page on safari it will scroll automatically at the bottom of the page for no reason. This bug appears **only** using Iphones.

I'm struggling to find where this bug comes from but I have no clue.

the only solution I found is :

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 800); 
}
```

Using `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`in componentDidMount() has no effect except if I'm using `setTimeout`, but I don't know think this is right way to do it..

When I'm clicking on link from the App I have no problems since I'm using this method https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/scroll-restoration.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found why I had this bad behavior on Safari Mobile.

In my app I have a component `AppContainer` which encapsulate all my routes

**routes.js**

```
 <AppContainer location={window.location}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignInContainer} />
    </Switch>
</AppContainer>
```

in which, I export default my class 
`export default withRouter((connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer)));`

It turns out that in this component, `componentDidMount()`was called before all the nested component in my routes. first problem I solved by adding `translate`in my export default.

Because I'm using [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) with options `react: { wait: true }`,
all nested children components have `export default translate(['common'))`.

that means every time a child is mounted it will wait to load all locales before the rendering, which is not the case with `AppContainer`that's why his `componentDidMount` was called first.

I just needed to add

`export default withRouter(
    translate([])(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer)),
);`

Now the lifecycle was fixed, I just need to add scrollBy on the `componentDidMount`in `AppContainer` and this time I used

**AppContainer**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, -5000);
    }, 0);
  }
```

and not an approximately time out of 800ms.

Hope it will help people who encounter the same issue.